# How create file and put it in a war with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3, war

How I can create file and put it in a war with Maven when building the war?

Comment: What kind of file?  A properties file?

Comment: `.properties` or `.txt` file.

Answer (score 1):

Maven builds a war by executing the war goal of the maven-war plugin. Have a look at the configuration parameters of this goal at http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html.

Basically, warSourceDirectory (defaulting to ${basedir}/src/main/webapp) contains the files that go to the war, apart from your java code and resources. Fine tune with packagingIncludes/packagingExcludes. To include file(s) from *another* module, use overlay: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/overlays.html.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you want a file that gets put on the classpath when your .jar or .war is assembled.  You likely want to put it in `src\main\resources`.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your using eclipse+maven.
put it Java resources>> package you want

then right click on the project maven>> update project.
run the new pom.xml you'll get the new .war with everything in place.